# Avoid repetition in similar boolean states

Tags: reactjs, react-native, refactoring, react-state

In my app I have two clickable texts with similar behaviors that are managing states that hold a boolean value to show or not a Modal in React Native.

```
      <View style={styles.resultContainer}>
        <View style={styles.teamContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.teamNameContainer} onPress={toggleIsVisibleTeamA}>
            <Text style={styles.teamNameText}>Team A</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.teamResultContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.teamResultText}>0</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <Text style={styles.resultDivider}>x</Text>

        <View style={styles.teamContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.teamNameContainer} onPress={toggleIsVisibleTeamB}>
            <Text style={styles.teamNameText}>Team B</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.teamResultContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.teamResultText}>0</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
```

I have the same logic for managing this states, just two function that I could write in-line but I spliced it for the organization

```
  function toggleIsVisibleTeamA() {
    setIsVisibleTeamA(!isVisibleTeamA);
  }

  function toggleIsVisibleTeamB() {
    setIsVisibleTeamB(!isVisibleTeamB);
  }
```

I know that this is not following the DRY principles and I can't figure out a way to refactor this piece of code any suggestions? I thought on making the state an object but that would make the logic more complex that it should I guess. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two separate states uses a single state as an object and pass on the key to be updated to the toggleIsVisibleFunction

```
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState({A: false, B: false});
...
function toggleIsVisibleTeam(team) {
    setIsVisible(prev=> ({
        ...prev,
        [team]: !prev[team]
    }));
}
...

 <View style={styles.resultContainer}>
        <View style={styles.teamContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.teamNameContainer} onPress={()=> toggleIsVisibleTeam('A')}>
            <Text style={styles.teamNameText}>Team A</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.teamResultContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.teamResultText}>0</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <Text style={styles.resultDivider}>x</Text>

        <View style={styles.teamContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.teamNameContainer} onPress={()=> toggleIsVisibleTeam('B')}>
            <Text style={styles.teamNameText}>Team B</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.teamResultContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.teamResultText}>0</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
```

And whereever you used `isVisibleTeamA` you would now use `isVisible.A`

P.S. You can improve further by rendering the JSX elements by mapping over an array

Comment: I don't feel like it's necessary to render the JSX with the map function as this is a unique case with just two teams, that would add unnecessary complexity to the component I guess. I'm using the map function in arrays with unknown size or similar elements that repeat a lot of times, I don't think this case needs it. Thank you for the answer the object will do it!